# Web project development in subfolder

Tags: php, html, frameworks, path

For example i am working on 2 projects, A & B, both of them in future will be hosted in root directories.
Atm i have one apache web server with default parameters and i want to start working, so i create folder A and folder B, where i will store all needed files.

The problem is when i ll use something like

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/resources/scripts/javascript.js" ></script>
<link  href="/resources/styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

both of the projects will call this files from apache root folder (httpdocs), not from /a/ and /b/ folders.

Things get worse when i am using PHP framework, so i cant just use

```
<link  href="./resources/styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

(dot before /resources/) because with routing project is trying to access controller like a folder and get resources from there.

Sounds like a small problem, but i cant figure it out and close this question for myself, so  each time i need to develop something i invent workarounds again and again :)

Comment: Create a `$baseURL` variable that you can edit in your project and append to the front of each link (essentially creating an absolute URL).

Comment: I just use apache virtual hosts so each projects sub folder is its own root folder

Comment: I thought about virtual hosts, but i didnt found how to setup them properly without domain name :)

Comment: You can use virtual hosts based on domain name, ip address or port, you can just add project.localhost to your hosts file and use that as the domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way of handling this is to use a constant that holds the path to your project. That way you only have to edit that constant to get your paths right.

```
define('BASEDIR', '/a/');
echo '
<script type="text/javascript"  src="'.BASEDIR.'resources/scripts/javascript.js" ></script>
<link href="'.BASEDIR.'resources/styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
```

This will turn your paths into

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="./a/resources/scripts/javascript.js" ></script>
<link href="./a/resources/styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
```

If you keep that constant in a seperate file you can include it where you'd need it. A php file that handles an AJAX request for instance.

Comment: The only remark, basedir must be without dot, or in situation when you use frameworks, path will start with controller and methods :)

Comment: @Nerfair I missed that in your question. Edited my answer to reflect it.

Comment: But isn't it too much unnecessary work to write basedir for any link in your project? :)

Comment: Like this 

**<a href="<?=ROOT;?>/post/<?= $aPost['id']; ?>"><?= $aPost['title']; ?></a>**

Comment: @Nerfair Don't use the quick open and close tags. Just do it like this: `<?php echo '<a href="'.ROOT.'/post/'.$aPost['id'].'">'.$aPost['title'].'</a>'; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .htaccess file in each of the project folders (if you have no access to httpd.conf)

```
ScriptAlias /resources/  "/var/www/html/resources/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/resources/">
   #... whatever you want to set here ...
</Directory>
```

Then you can continue to use

```
script type="text/javascript"  src="/resources/scripts/javascript.js" ></script>
<link  href="/resources/styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```